# Bead Separated from Fabric

Tags: tire

The metal bead on my tire seems to have come out of the fabric in one spot, and so the tire no longer stays in the rim. Is it possible to fix this, or do I need to get a new tire?

Comment: Sewing with fishing line has worked for me in the past, very well actually, but I would not use it anymore, I think it's not worth the hand labor and the risk of problems. Anyway, it's a possibility for large-volume, low pressure tires.

Comment: Since you took time to post this, I assume you are not stranded and need a way to get back home any way possible. Get a new tire. If you ARE stranded, you could try to stitch it up, or I have used duct tape to fix this problem in the past. Fold a section of tube, longer than the slice, in half and wrap it a couple times with tape. Then tape that over the hole as close as you can to the bottom of the bead, maybe slightly over lapping. Let the duct tape wrap all the way to the tread, pump the tire, then rip the tape off at the rim. Get home and buy a new tire!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the bead is popping out, you're going to need a new tire. Your tube could have a blow out through the gap. You may want to inspect your brakes and make sure they were not rubbing on the tire.  This could be causing pre-mature wear around the edge of the tire near the bead.

Comment: Darn, was hoping that wasn't the answer ;) Not sure if it was the brakes, the tire is brand new and this happened within the first hour of riding. Might just be me being a dumbass and not putting in the tire properly, or maybe just a defective tire.

Comment: This can happen if the (as you surmised) the brakes are rubbing against the tire. make sure your brake pads are centered on the braking surface and don't touch the tire. If they don't fit on the braking surface, err below rather than touching tire (but you should also swap out the pads if this is the case).

Comment: If the tire is new, ask for warranty on your shop!

Comment: Yeah. It's going to be obvious that it was premature failure of the tire. Take it back for a replacement.

Comment: Take it back for replacement *if* the failure's not due to the brake blocks rubbing on the tire.

Answer (score 0):

Patch from inside with thick strip of inner tube with rubber cement, stitch the patch in place with heavy duty nylon thread allowing @ least 1/4" to 3/8" clearance so as to not provide the tear any additional "path of least resistance" on which to travel, (grow). Ensure your stitches are tidy, evenly spaced and going the same direction as opposed to zig-zaging. When finished, your handwork should resemble the inside of a Jordan sneaker without the insole (as far as the stitches are concerned.